# Creating default object from empty value (adding an item to a database for a new user in Laravel)

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-4

I have a function I am using to add

I have an array $data that contains the user data I am trying to put into the db.  Everything works except for the "makeUrlTag" function portion:

```
public function makeUrlTag() {

        $url_tag = '';
        if(isset($this->data['user']['first_name'])) {
        $url_tag = $url_tag . $this->data['user']['first_name'];
        }
        if(isset($this->data['user']['last_name'])) {
        $url_tag = $url_tag.$this->data['user']['last_name'];
        }

        $fan->url_tag = $url_tag;

    }

public function createFan() {
        $fan                        = new Fan;
        $fan->fbid                  = isset($this->data['user']['id']) ? $this->data['user']['id'] : '';
        $fan->email                 = isset($this->data['user']['email']) ? $this->data['user']['email'] : '';
        $fan->first_name            = isset($this->data['user']['first_name']) ? $this->data['user']['first_name'] : '';
        $fan->last_name             = isset($this->data['user']['last_name']) ? $this->data['user']['last_name'] : '';


        $this->makeUrlTag();

        $fan->save();
    }
```

I call createFan with:

```
$this->createFan();
```

When I run this, I get the error:

```
Creating default object from empty value
```

in reference to the makeUrlTag(); portion.  Particularly the line:

```
$fan->url_tag = $url_tag;
```

Any idea what's going on here?  Again, taking out the makeUrlTag portion works fine.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your `makeUrlTag()` method doesn't know about the `Fan` which is in the `$fan` variable you created in the `createFan()` method and trying to use a non-existing object in the scope of `makeUrlTag()` method using this:

```
$fan->url_tag = $url_tag;
```

So, you need to make your `$fan` object available to `makeUrlTag()` and to do this you may add a `protected` property in your class:

```
class YourClass {

    protected $fan = null;

    public function makeUrlTag(){

        $url_tag = '';

        // ...

        $this->fan->url_tag = $url_tag;

    }

    public function makeUrlTag(){

        $this->fan = new Fan;

        // rest of your code
        // but use $this->fan instead of $fan

        $this->fan->save();

    }

}
```

So, now you can access the `$fan` object from any method of your class ussing `$this->fan`, that's it.